# Unity5, This renderer has more materials than the Mesh has submeshes

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 5 I notice a warning that is not present in Unity 4. Is there any problem with it and how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a performance notification not a real problem.
The problem is that when your mesh has more than 65534 vertices, your mesh is automatically divided into sub-meshes. 
In your case if you have 1 mesh with more than 1 material, it is multiplied by sub-mesh divisions, and your performance will be affected because each material will result in a draw-call.

I.E Your mesh has 320.000 vertices and 5 materials ... you got:

- 5 sub-meshes with 65534 vertices x 5 materials = 25 draw-calls